# Проблема с функцией Swap C++

Tags: c++, list, циклы, односвязный-список

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема с циклом сортировки односвязного списка? Судя по всему, указатель корректно перемещается (?), так как, если список изначально отсортирован, то все прекрасно работает, доходит до конца и останавливается, но после функции Swap начинаются проблемы с выходом из цикла.

Функция сортировки:

```
Queue* SortListOfPointsByX(Queue* q) {
    Element* current = q->head;
    while (current != nullptr) {
        if (LessThan((current->next->point.x), (current->point.x))) {
            SwapElementsOfList(current, current->next);
            std::cout << "\n\n";
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    PrintListOfPoints(q);
    std::cout << "Сортировка завершена.\n";
    return q;
}
```

Функция Swap:

```
void SwapElementsOfList(Element* elem1, Element* elem2) {
    Element* next_temp = elem2;
    elem2->next = elem1;
    elem1->next = next_temp;

    Point point_temp = elem2->point;
    elem2->point = elem1->point;
    elem1->point = point_temp;
}
```

Comment: у вас в сортировке обращаетесь с указателем по нулевому адресу `current->next->point.x` должна была система вас остановить. Или всё будет двигаться неопределённо. Проверять указатель `current->next == nullptr` на нулевой нужно сразу. Какие ещё ошибки у вас не вижу, вы не выкладывали. Этого уже достаточно.

Answer (score 2):

Тут вы зацикливаете свой список:

```
Element* next_temp = elem2;
elem2->next = elem1;
elem1->next = next_temp;
```

В итоге elem1 указывает на elem2, а elem2 на elem1.

В конце вызова вашей функции elem1->next должен указывать на элемент, стоявщий после узла elem2 до начала выполнения функции:

```
Element* next_temp = elem2->next;
elem2->next = elem1;
elem1->next = next_temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы поменять в односвязном списке соседние элементы, необходимо иметь указатель на предыдущий узел. Т.е. чтобы поменять местами `node2` и `node3`, нужно изменить указатель `node1->next`, который указывал на `node2`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А если менять местами не соседние элементы, то нужно знать предыдущие узлы обоих элементов.
В принципе можете в функцию передавать указатели на предыдущие узлы элементов, которые нужно поменять местами. Чтобы не заморачиваться с началом и концом списка, просто список закольцуйте.
Поскольку в цикле вы меняете местами соседние элементы, то можете переписать функцию примерно так:

```
// обмен соседних элементов списка
// Внимание! Не проверяется начало и конец списка! - будет работать если список закольцован
void SwapCurrNextElem(Element* PrevElem) // передается указатель на предыдущий элемент от тех, которые меняются местами
{  
   Element* elem1 = PrevElem->next;
   Element* elem2 = elem1->next;
   
   elem1->next = elem2->next;
   elem2->next = elem1;
   PrevElem->next = elem2;

// Далее обмен значениями элементов
}
```

И правильно написал AlexGlebe - в цикле вы проверяете только `(current != nullptr)`, а ещё нужно проверять `(current->next != nullptr)`, потому что если вы дошли до последнего узла, то `current != nullptr` а `current->next == nullptr` и при попытке прочитать значение `current->next->point.x` вы по сути получаете обращение по нулевому указателю `nullptr->point.x`.